# Specify datatemplate for same model but for different controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatemplate

For example we have:

```
public class CmdData  
{
    public CmdData(String text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }

    public CmdData(String text, ICommand command): this(text)
    {
        Command = command;
    }

    public String Text { get; set; }
    public ICommand Command { get; set; }


}
```

It is used as a model for MenuItem.
Next I inroduce new entity CheckableCmdData( : CmdData) and want to use them in ToolBar and Menu.

In Menu CheckableCmdData is a MenuItem with IsCheckable="True". In toolbar it is a CheckBox.

I have a DataTemplate For Menu.
What is the apropriate way to create DataTemplate for same model but for different controls or should I use styles instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for me is an implementation of ItemTemplateSelector.

Answer (score 0):

You may create separate data templates, assign them different resource keys and apply an appropriate template for the specific control.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MenuCmdDataTemplate"
              DataType="{x:Type local:CmdData}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="MenuCheckableCmdDataTemplate"
              DataType="{x:Type local:CheckableCmdData}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="ToolBarCmdDataTemplate"
              DataType="{x:Type local:CmdData}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"
               Foreground="Red"/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="ToolBarCheckableCmdDataTemplate"
              DataType="{x:Type local:CheckableCmdData}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"
                   Foreground="Green"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

And usage:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ToolBar VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Button Content="{Binding}"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ToolBarCmdDataTemplate}"
                DataContext="{Binding CmdData1}"/>
        <Button Content="{Binding}"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ToolBarCheckableCmdDataTemplate}"
                DataContext="{Binding CmdData2}"/>
    </ToolBar>
    <Menu VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="Group">
            <MenuItem HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MenuCmdDataTemplate}"
                      DataContext="{Binding CmdData1}"
                      Header="{Binding}"/>
            <MenuItem HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MenuCheckableCmdDataTemplate}"
                      DataContext="{Binding CmdData2}"
                      Header="{Binding}"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</StackPanel>
```